# I am getting a Data Store error in Roblox Studio that fails my data store. I have enabled studio access to API services

Tags: lua, syntax-error, game-development, roblox-studio

I made this simple datastore script that should load the datastore and add the values to your leaderstats. It fails at line 29, which is marked in the script. What am I doing wrong?

```lua
local dts = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local money = dts:GetDataStore("Currency-0")



--Currency is set up like this:

--{CASH, GEMS}

--It is a table storing both values.


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
local model = Instance.new("Model") -- lets set up our leaderstats!
    model.Name = "leaderstats"
    model.Parent = plr
local moneyValue = Instance.new("IntValue")
    moneyValue.Name = "Cash"
local gemValue = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gemValue.Name = "Gems"
    
local key = "USER_" .. plr.Name .. "_" .. plr.UserId -- advanced player key

local storedCash -- setting up a variable
local success, err = pcall(function()
    storedCash = money:GetAsync(key)
end)
if success then
    moneyValue.Value = storedCash[1] -- this is the line that messes up
    gemValue.Value = storedCash[2]
    -- we've set that, now we must make it show
    moneyValue.Parent = model
else
    moneyValue.Value = 0
    gemValue.Value = 0
    money:SetAsync(key, {0, 0}) 
end
end)
```

My error: :29: attempt to index local 'storedCash' (a nil value)

I made a simple datastore script, and it should have been adding the values to the leaderstats. But it shows an error on line 29, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That’s not how you use the until statement. Your until statement with the wait is saying "if `wait(5)` doesn’t return anything", which is just as much a terrible abuse of the until statement as using it for the while condition. It’s bad for readability as well.

This is what I would do instead:

```
local success, result do
    repeat
        success, result = pcall(money.GetAsync, money, key)
        if not success then
            wait(5)
        end
    until success or MAX_RETRIES
```

A note on `MAX_RETRIES:` this is a placeholder making a note that you should add a retry cap. Repeatedly calling this function is bad use of `DataStores`. It would create a loop that runs forever until `DataStores` return true, which can cause an issue if `DataStores` are down or the call is not succeeding. I’m not sure why you would use a loop statement with data anyway.

The simple response here is to do error handling. If there’s no data in the key (which then `GetAsync` returns nil), you handle that case instead of making a loop.

```
local success, result = pcall(money.GetAsync, money, key)
if success then
    if result then
        -- Data non-nil
    else
        -- Data nil
    end
else
    -- Success false, do something about it
end
```